# 64-bit Virtual Address Space Size

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, virtual-memory

I was reading [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details) about this size of the virtual address space in x86-64 and it said the virtual address space is 2^64 bytes in size. Why is it not 2^67 bytes, derived from there being 2^64 addresses and each address being 8 bytes?

For this question I am not concerned about the specifics of x86 where not all of the virtual address space is used etc.

Comment: You confuse things. A byte is **eight bits**. An address is 64 bits which are stored in 8 bytes. But it points to **one byte** only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each address refers to ONE byte. Not, eight.

Systems these days are byte addressable; not word addressable as in ye olde days.

Comment: Oh wow, that is the simplest answer ever and I totally overlooked it! Thank you stranger! :)

Comment: Even if the x86 was word-addressable, the address space would still be 2^64. The size of the address space determines the number of *objects* that can be addressed. Each object can be a bit, a byte, a word, anything.

Comment: @MargaretBloom but say you wanted to store the entire address space, then you _would_ need to know the size of the objects at each address. Right?

Comment: @peachykeen Yes, of course. The size is always documented as it reflects how the instructions work and are encoded. In case of x86, it's always been 8-bit.